# express mysql sessions

Tags: mysql, session, node.js, express

I cant find a good way to use sessions stored in mysql with express and node.js. Anyone has some tips of modules or a way to achieve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created a very simple MySQL session store called **[connect-mysql-session](https://github.com/CarnegieLearning/connect-mysql-session)**.  This is handy if you already have a MySQL database handy and want to use it to persist sessions.  Install it via npm with:

```
[sudo] npm install [-g] connect-mysql-session
```

Comment: This module has gone unsupported for 2 years. I created a new one (with unit and integration testing):
https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session

Answer (score 2):

There are currently seven session connection management middleware for connect (upon which express runs) that I am aware of:

express-session (bundled with express, uses MemoryStore)

connect-redis https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis

connect-mongodb https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb

connect-couchdb https://github.com/tdebarochez/connect-couchdb

connect-memcached https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached

nstore-session https://github.com/creationix/nstore-session

cookie-sessions (stores sessions in client-side cookies) https://github.com/caolan/cookie-sessions

In able to use Mysql as a session store, someone would need to create a connect middleware for it. (connect-redis is only 125 lines so it's probably not a herculean task.)